# How do I extract the path and filename from a media player playlist to copy the files to a new location?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a script that will read a windows media playlist file and extract the path and filename of all the songs in the playlist and copy the files to a single folder. I am not sure how to strip out the text between the

Comment: can you show what you have tried yet

Comment: I have not tried anything yet. I am just learning the commands or I guess they shoukd be called cmdlets. I am still looking for what commands I can use to get the info from the file to something powershell can use.

Answer (score 1):

```
$wpl = Get-Content "C:\Temp\test.wpl"

foreach ($line in $wpl) {
    If ($line -match "<media src=*") {
        $file = $line.split("`n")|%{
        $_.split('"')[1]}

        Copy-Item $file "C:\Temp"
    }
}
```

Tested on Win7 and MediaPlayer 12

Comment: That almost works except if fails for any file that has an apostrophy in the song title because of the way thay are stored in the windows media player playlist files (['] becomes [&apos] Something I did not realize until I tried your solution. But then I discovered that media player can create .m3u playlist files and they don;t manipulate the file nems at all. Now I just need to figure out how to extract any line that does not start with a # or is blank. Thanis for the jump start anyway.

Answer (score 1):

For .m3u Files you can do the job with this code:

```
$list = Get-Content "C:\Temp\test.m3u" | ? { $_ -notmatch "^$|^\s+$" }

foreach ($line in $list) {
    If ($line -notmatch '#' ) {
        Copy-Item $line "C:\Temp"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work for m3u files.

```
    $PlaylistName = Read-Host 'Playlist filename (Include drive and path):'
    $Directory = Read-Host 'Target Directory (Include drive and path):'
    Write-Host "Searching "$PlaylistName" for media files and copying to "$Directory"`n"
    (Get-Content $PlaylistName) | where {$+.trim() -ne "" } | Out-File Temp.txt
    (Get-Content Temp.txt) | Select-String -pattern "#EXTINF:0" -notmatch | Out-File first.txt
    (Get-Content first.txt) | Select-String -pattern "#EXTM3U" -notmatch | Out-File final.txt
    Copy-Item (Get-Content final.txt $Directory
```

Still needs alot of cleanup and much improvement and possibly a gui interface but I am working on that stuff.